# Как правильно написать значение атрибута name в input?

Tags: html

Какой самый верный подход и чтобы без ошибок при отправки по ajax или при различных вариантов изменений?

Некоторые пишут что нужно через `-` а некоторые что правильней через `_`

Есть какой то стандарт как нужно правильно писать?

```js
console.log( $('input[name="name-id"]').val() );
console.log( $('input[name="name_id"]').val() );
console.log( $('input[name="nameId"]').val() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="name-id" value="test1">
<input type="text" name="name_id" value="test2">
<input type="text" name="nameId" value="test3">
```

Comment: Выберите для себя и следуйте)) Если серваку проще работать с camelCase то делайте такое имя..... имя через дефис - самое отстойное)) и вроде нигде не применяется

Comment: Технически нет никакой разницы